# update-initramfs generates junk images that should not exist

Tags: boot, kernel, configuration, initramfs

Maybe someone will need this :)

Basically, some time ago I was tinkering with initramfs compression modes, and had created a one-liner to only update current initramfs image. Through trial and error, I succeed. However, because I was a noob with bash in general, I created a problem.

Terminal output when trying to update all initrd images:

```
root@OMEN:/boot# update-initramfs -k all -c
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-{uname
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/{uname
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed {uname
dpkg: įspėjimas: version '{uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
dpkg: įspėjimas: version '{uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed {uname
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img--r}
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-(uname
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/(uname
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed (uname
dpkg: įspėjimas: version '(uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
dpkg: įspėjimas: version '(uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed (uname
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img--r)
```

How do I get rid of all these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was how update-initramfs tool has the idea of these "versions" (how it managed to "generate" them is another :D)? To find...

1. `cd` (go to) into the directory:

   ```
   lukas@OMEN:/etc/initramfs-tools$ cd /var/lib/initramfs-tools
   ```
2. `ls` (list) the files in current directory:

   ```
   lukas@OMEN:/var/lib/initramfs-tools$ ls
   '-r)'   -r}  '(uname'   {uname  '(uname -r)'  '{uname -r}'
   ```

   Here we can see these files. Just proceed deleting them one-by-one, if you recognize something else you may need, or just remove them all:

   ```
   lukas@OMEN:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/*
   ```

Now, delete the junk files in `/boot`...
First, check what files are there:

```
lukas@OMEN:~$ ls /boot
 boot                          initrd.img-5.7.10-xanmod2     System.map-5.4.0-42-generic
 config-5.3.0-62-generic       initrd.img-5.7.11-xanmod1     System.map-5.7.10-xanmod2
 config-5.4.0-42-generic       initrd.img-{uname             System.map-5.7.11-xanmod1
 config-5.7.10-xanmod2        'initrd.img-{uname -r}'        vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic
 config-5.7.11-xanmod1         lost+found                    vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
 efi                           memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-5.7.10-xanmod2
 grub                          memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-5.7.11-xanmod1
 initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic   memtest86+_multiboot.bin
 initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic   System.map-5.3.0-62-generic
```

Then delete the files you recognize to be junk ones
(**be careful**, deleting wrong files can make your system unbootable):

```
lukas@OMEN:~$ sudo rm "/boot/initrd.img-{uname -r}"
```

If the files have space symbol or some weird symbols, put the argument after `rm` in quotes (both `'` and `"` work)

If you did accidentally delete an image that was needed, **do not** reboot your computer, first do this:

0. Type in terminal `uname -r`, then `sudo ls /boot` and check if running kernel still has initrd image (should be `initrd.img-VERSION`, where `VERSION` is the output from `uname -r`). If there is such a file, you will be able to reboot your PC into GNU/Linux. Following next steps are still recommended, though.
1. Open up Synaptic or Muon (if neither are installed, `sudo apt install synaptic`), then launch from your dash or application menu.
2. Search for installed `linux-image` packages (put what is in quotes into search box, wait a sec for the application to load package list, then sort packages by "installed version" or "status".
3. Reinstall everything that shows a "installed version" or has status "installed" down below.
4. Check `/boot` directory with `ls /boot` again, and if you have the initrd images again, you can relax and do what you want, successful reboot included.